# How to programmatically clear TextInputEditText in Android

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext, autocompletesupportfragment

I do not want to `setText("")` to clear the text.
I want to simulator the click action of right cross icon.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [the implementation of that icon](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/ClearTextEndIconDelegate.java#L90-L96), call `setText(null)` on the `TextInputEditText`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (editText != null) {

    editText.getText().clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

( Using Kotlin )

```
[your ID right cross icon].setOnClickListener {
   [your ID edit text].text.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment).setText(null)
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/widget/AutocompleteSupportFragment#public-autocompletesupportfragment-settext-charsequence-text

It will do exactly what the clear icon does.